# How to wipe a specific region of a hard drive partition?

Tags: hard-drive, security, filesystems, privacy, wipe

I need to wipe (securely erase) a specific part (the last third) of a partition, wiping the whole partition free space is not an option (as other regions contain deleted data that *must* stay recoverable).

The only idea I can see now is to truncate the partition, create a new partition on the place to wipe and wipe it.

Isn't there a better way? A wiping tool which can start wiping from a specific offset (given in gigagabytes)?

The file system is NTFS, the OS is Windows 7 but I wouldn't mind using a LiveCD of a sort.

Comment: I don't think the FS would remain intact after you start shredding it. Why don't you save down the data you need and wipe the disc with nuke n boot for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use *nix `dd` (available on any Linux Live CD) with `/dev/urandom` as source. 
`seek` parameter will tell `dd` how many blocks to skip on destination device. You may also run it several times of course to make sure any residual is gone. [This thread](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/learn-the-dd-command-362506/) has lots and lots of examples on `dd` usage.

**Warning: `dd` is very powerful and very indiscriminate. It will happily chew you hdd dead faster than you say 'Oh my..' if you did something wrong!**

**Make an image of your drive before you start (which `dd` can be used for as well)**

Note: You could also test all your changes on an image which is generally safer, and said image can be also mounted similar to real hdd (so called loop device)

Comment: An elegant idea. I didn't knew of the `seek` parameter to skip blocks on destination device. I used to use `dd` for making images. But this way seems to be not fool-proof at all and I have actually no chance to backup the HDD. I think I am going just try this on a different drive first.

Comment: @Ivan Certainly not foolprof :-) btw You may also want to use `-count` to limit number of blocks written; and make sure partitions you alter are not mounted.